# How to use Regex to get nested matches including their capturing groups?

Tags: regex, regex-group, regexp-replace

I have a string with a nested pattern `func(func(doSomething))` and I have a Regex expression: `/func\(([^ ]*)\)/gm`. I want to get two separate matches where:

**Match 1**:

**match**: func(func(doSomething))
**group captured**:func(doSomething)

**Match 2**: 
**match**: func(doSomething)
**group captured**:doSomething

However, I'm only getting a single match with the entire inner 'func' being a capturing group.
Here is the regex link: https://regex101.com/r/dUa4SC/1
**Is it possible to achieve this using regex? if so Please help me with it**. 
Thanks

Comment: In JS there is afaik no regex recursion. If you know the max depth you can expand the pattern for each level. E.g. for max two levels deep [like this demo](https://regex101.com/r/9Z6PX8/1).

Answer (score 1):

You can build a recursive function to check the regex over the matched groups, in JavaScript it would be something like this:

```
function RecursiveMatch(pattern, text){

  let matches = text.match(pattern);

  if(matches != null && matches.length > 1){
    console.log(matches[1] + " found in "+ matches[0])
    RecursiveMatch(pattern, matches[1])
  }    
}

RecursiveMatch("func\\\(([^ ]*)\\\)", "func(func(doSomething))");
```

And this is the output:

```
func(doSomething) found in func(func(doSomething))
doSomething found in func(doSomething)
```

Comment: Is it possible to achieve the same in javascript?

Comment: of course, I edited the answer